# difference between vidalia bridge bundle, vidalia relay bundle and vidalia exit bundle

Tags: vidalia

I am using vidalia from past 3 years. I used to simply download latest version of vidalia bundle from the tor website, change configuration and use it for browsing via different browsers.

Previously there was single vidalia bundle, but now there are three options vidalia bridge bundle, vidalia relay bundle and vidalia exit bundle.

Now i am totally confused which bundle to download and what are the differences between these bundles. I tried searching for the differences between them on the official site but with no luck.

Can someone please explain it in easy language. ..

Answer (score 1):

Vidalia is not part anymore of the standard Tor Browser Bundle. It will be completely discontinued soon.

Besides, the differences between these Bundles you name are their default configurations, since they are tailored to suit a user who wants to run specifically a bridge, a relay and an exit node.